# interpreting Principal Components Analysis results

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I am trying to use the eigenvectors (or weights) to make sense on what features are primarily influencing the principal components. For this purpose, I use `pca.components_` where `pca` results from fitting the model to the given data. Some of my features can have values ranging e.g from 1 to 5, where 1 would mean 'highest' and 5 'lowest'. But a large absolute value of the weight (which could be positive or negative) just tells me that **the feature itself is important**, right? IMO this is not sufficient information to gain further insights, so in this example to be able to tell if it is high or low income. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You sound confused. I kindly suggest you go again through the whole PCA theory & methodology; PCA has absolutely nothing to do with feature importance (it does not even take into account the dependent variable).

Comment: "Importance" is a subjective term and depends on your goal (e.g., classification, compression). What you can do with PCA to aid in variable selection is quantify the correlations of input variables with principal components via **loadings**. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another) for an explanation and links to resources.